# Unresolved Kotlin reference in mixed Java/Kotlin multimodule project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

As title. `gradle build` works in command line. All tests pass. However, in IntelliJ I get `unresolved reference` for things like `listOf()`, `setOf()`, `coerceAtMost()`, etc. Basically some Kotlin native library functions.

My IntelliJ Kotlin plugin version is 1.3.72, and I force 1.3.72 in the build.gradle files. My IntelliJ version is 2020.2. I've done "Invalidate Caches/Restart" multiple times.

My project structure is as follows:

```
root
-- build.gradle
-- settings.gradle
-- server-root
  -- server-base
    -- src/main/java
    -- src/main/kotlin
    -- test/java
    -- test/kotlin
    -- build.gradle
  -- server-module-1
    // empty for now
  -- server-module-2
    // empty for now
```

My base `root/settings.gradle`

```
...
include(":server-base")
...
project(":server-base").projectDir = file('server-root/server-base')
```

My base `root/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.2.1" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.72" apply false
    id "nebula.lint" version "16.9.0"
    id 'idea'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

My `server-root/server-base/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(:'server-module-1')
    ...
}
```

I've tried basically every StackOverflow solution I could find and still IntelliJ gives me this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does Build | rebuild Project action work?

Comment: Try File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | Invalidate and Restart  action and open project via File | New | Project from Existing Sources action and select main build.gradle file to import from. Also try version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ If issue remains provide a sample project and zipped logs to check (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data action).

Comment: Check my answer. Really strange situation that was solved by the most simple fix >.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the Kotlin plugin to the latest: 203-1.4.21-release-IJ6682.9. (Using the IntelliJ updater, not manual download). And my IntelliJ version to 2020.3.

So even though the Kotlin plugin version doesn't the Kotlin version Gradle is setting, it works..